# Chord Progression Map using Pgf / TiKz

Tags: tikz-pgf

It is needed to implement a Chord Progression Map using Pgf / TiKz for music lecture.
The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc, shapes, arrows}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}

\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [parent anchor=east,child anchor=west,grow=east]
        \tikzstyle{title}=[font=\fontsize{18}{18}\color{green!65}\sffamily]
        \tikzstyle{raiz}=[ball color=white,circle,text=black,anchor=west]
        \tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[draw=none,dashed,thick,red]
        \node [title] (romanNumber) at (1.5, 4) {I};
        \node[raiz] (ch0) {C}
        child {node[right] (ch5) {maj6}}
        child {node[right] (ch4) {maj6/9}}
        child {node[right] (ch3) {maj9}}
        child {node[right] (ch2) {maj7}}
        child {node[right] (ch1) {maj}};
        \node[fit=(romanNumber)(ch0)(ch5)(ch1)(ch4), draw,rounded corners=0.5cm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}    \qquad    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [parent anchor=east,child anchor=west,grow=east]
        \tikzstyle{title}=[font=\fontsize{18}{18}\color{green!65}\sffamily]
        \tikzstyle{raiz}=[ball color=white,circle,text=black,anchor=west]
        \tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[draw=none,dashed,thick,red]
        \node [title] (romanNumber) at (1.5, 3) {iii};
        \node[raiz] (ch0) {E}
        child {node[right] (ch4) {maj6}}
        child {node[right] (ch3) {min9}}
        child {node[right] (ch2) {min7}}
        child {node[right] (ch1) {min}};
        \node[fit=(romanNumber)(ch0)(ch1)(ch4), draw,rounded corners=0.5cm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}    \qquad    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [parent anchor=east,child anchor=west,grow=east]
        \tikzstyle{title}=[font=\fontsize{18}{18}\color{green!65}\sffamily]
        \tikzstyle{raiz}=[ball color=white,circle,text=black,anchor=west]
        \tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[draw=none,dashed,thick,red]
        \node [title] (romanNumber) at (1.5, 2.5) {vi};
        \node[raiz] (ch01) {A}
        child {node[right] (ch11) {min9}}
        child {node[right] (ch12) {min7}}
        child {node[right] (ch13) {min}};
        \node[below = 2cm of ch01,raiz] (ch02) {C}
        child {node[right] (ch12) {maj6}};
        \node[fit=(romanNumber)(ch01)(ch11)(ch02)(ch12), draw,rounded corners=0.5cm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}    \qquad    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [parent anchor=east,child anchor=west,grow=east]
        \tikzstyle{title}=[font=\fontsize{18}{18}\color{green!65}\sffamily]
        \tikzstyle{raiz}=[ball color=white,circle,text=black,anchor=west]
        \tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[draw=none,dashed,thick,red]
        \node [title] (romanNumber) at (1.5, 3) {ii};
        \node[raiz] (ch01) {D}
        child {node[right] (ch11) {min9}}
        child {node[right] (ch12) {min7}}
        child {node[right] (ch13) {min}};
        \node[below = 2cm of ch01,raiz] (ch02) {F}
        child {node[right] (ch12) {maj6}};
        \node[fit=(romanNumber)(ch01)(ch11)(ch02)(ch12), draw,rounded corners=0.5cm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}    \qquad    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [parent anchor=east,child anchor=west,grow=east]
        \tikzstyle{title}=[font=\fontsize{18}{18}\color{green!65}\sffamily]
        \tikzstyle{raiz}=[ball color=white,circle,text=black,anchor=west]
        \tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[draw=none,dashed,thick,red]
        \node [title] (romanNumber) at (1.5, 4) {IV};
        \node[raiz] (ch01) {D}
        child {node[right] (ch11) {maj6}}
        child {node[right] (ch12) {maj6/9}}
        child {node[right] (ch12) {maj9}}
        child {node[right] (ch12) {maj7}}
        child {node[right] (ch13) {maj}};
        \node[below = 4.1cm of ch01,raiz] (ch02) {D}
        child {node[right] (ch12) {min7}};
        \node[fit=(romanNumber)(ch01)(ch13)(ch02)(ch12), draw,rounded corners=0.5cm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}    \qquad    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [parent anchor=east,child anchor=west,grow=east]
        \tikzstyle{title}=[font=\fontsize{18}{18}\color{green!65}\sffamily]
        \tikzstyle{raiz}=[ball color=white,circle,text=black,anchor=west]
        \tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[draw=none,dashed,thick,red]
        \node [title] (romanNumber) at (1.5, 4) {I};
        \node[raiz] (ch0) {C}
        child {node[right] (ch5) {maj6}}
        child {node[right] (ch4) {maj6/9}}
        child {node[right] (ch3) {maj9}}
        child {node[right] (ch2) {maj7}}
        child {node[right] (ch1) {maj}};
        \node[fit=(romanNumber)(ch0)(ch5)(ch1)(ch4), draw,rounded corners=0.5cm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}    \qquad    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [parent anchor=east,child anchor=west,grow=east]
        \tikzstyle{title}=[font=\fontsize{18}{18}\color{green!65}\sffamily]
        \tikzstyle{raiz}=[ball color=white,circle,text=black,anchor=west]
        \tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[draw=none,dashed,thick,red]
        \node [title] (romanNumber) at (1.5, 3) {V};
        \node[raiz] (ch01) {G}
        child {node[right] (ch11) {7\#5}}
        child {node[right] (ch12) {dom9}}
        child {node[right] (ch12) {dom7}}
        child {node[right] (ch13) {maj}};
        \node[below = 2.5cm of ch01,raiz] (ch02) {Db}
        child {node[right] (ch12) {dom7}};
        \node[fit=(romanNumber)(ch01)(ch11)(ch02)(ch12), draw,rounded corners=0.5cm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture} \qquad    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [parent anchor=east,child anchor=west,grow=east]
        \tikzstyle{title}=[font=\fontsize{18}{18}\color{green!65}\sffamily]
        \tikzstyle{raiz}=[ball color=white,circle,text=black,anchor=west]
        \tikzstyle{edge from parent}=[draw=none,dashed,thick,red]
        \node [title] (romanNumber) at (1.5, 2) {vii};
        \node[raiz] (ch01) {B}
        child {node[right] (ch11) {m7b5}}
        child {node[right] (ch12) {dim}};
        \node[below = 1.5cm of ch01,raiz] (ch02) {D}
        child {node[right] (ch21) {min6}};
        \node[fit=(romanNumber)(ch01)(ch11)(ch02)(ch21), draw,rounded corners=0.5cm] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Chord Progression Map}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow:

[image: desired]

---

**EDIT**

Now, the basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, graphs, chains, ext.paths.ortho, ext.positioning-plus}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        chord list/.style args={#1/#2:#3}{
            matrix, rectangle, draw={#1}, fill={#1!10}, rounded corners, thick, name=#2,
            label={[anchor=north, node font=\Large\sffamily, text={#1}]north:{#2}},
            node contents={\tikzset{create chord list={#2}{#3}}\pgfmatrixendrow}},
        circ node/.style={
            thin, draw, fill=white, circle, inner sep=+.15em,
            text width=width("D$\flat$"), align=center},
        chord node/.style={inner xsep=+.15em, text depth=+0pt},
        create chord list/.code 2 args={
            \tikzset{node distance=+.2em and +.5em, start chain=chord#1 going west below, anchor=center}
            \path (up:2.3em);
            \foreach[remember=\first (initially 1), count=\i] \t/\N in {#2}{
                \foreach \n in \N \node[on chain, chord node] {\n};
                \node[circ node, left=of (chord#1-\first)(chord#1-\tikzchaincount)] (chord#1-label-\i) {\t};
                \unless\ifnum\first=\tikzchaincount\relax
                \path[black, thin] (chord#1-label-\i)
                edge (chord#1-\first.mid west) edge (chord#1-\tikzchaincount.mid west);
                \fi
                \edef\first{\pgfinteval{\tikzchaincount+1}}}}]
        %% Inicia dibujo
        \draw[thick,-LaTeX] (1.4,5.6) -- ++(-1:0.6);
        \draw[thick,-LaTeX] (1.4,4.5) -- ++(-20:0.6);
        \draw[thick,-LaTeX] (1.4,3.2) -- ++(-40:0.6);
        \draw[thick,-LaTeX] (0.5,2.7) -- ++(-70:0.6);
        \draw[thick,-LaTeX] (-0.3,2.7) -- ++(-95:0.6);
        \matrix[                      chord list=green/iii:E/{min, min7, min9, maj6}];
        \matrix[above=1.5cm of iii,  chord list=green/I:C/{maj, maj7, maj9, maj6/9, maj6}];
        \matrix[north right=  of iii, chord list=green/vi:{A/{min, min7, min9}, C/maj6}];
        \matrix[north right=  of vi,  chord list=blue/ii:{F/{min, min7, min9}, F/maj6}];
        \matrix[north right=  of ii,  chord list=blue/IV:{F/{maj, maj7, maj9, maj6/9, maj6}, D/min7}];
        \matrix[north right=2:of IV,  chord list=green/I:C/{maj, maj7, maj9, maj6/9, maj6}];
        \matrix[above=.5cm of (IV)(I),chord list=red/V:{G/{maj, dom7, dom9, 7$\sharp$5}, D$\flat$/dom7}];
        \matrix[below=.5cm of (IV)(I),chord list=red/vii:{B/{dim, m7$\flat$5}, D/min6}];
        \graph[
        edges={thick, >=Latex, only horizontal first},
        use existing nodes,
        oi/.style args={#1:#2}{out={#1}, in={#2}}]{
            iii -> vi -> ii -> IV <->[only horizontal second] I,
            iii ->[bend left, left anchor=north, right anchor=90] ii,
            vi <->[bend right, left anchor=south, right anchor=230] IV,
            iii <-[oi=-90:200] vii,
            V <->[oi=  0: 90] I,
            (V.200) <->[oi=180: 90] IV,
            V      <-[oi=180: 85] ii,
            (V.160) <->[oi=180: 90] vi,
            ii ->[oi=-90:180] vii,
            IV ->[oi=-90:160] vii
            ->[oi=  0:-90] I
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: solved]

Solved !!!

Comment: Well, did you try something? This is probably not too difficult using the `fit` library ...

Comment: It is needed to implement output arrows for the top left block matrix...

Comment: This question has been changed quite fundamentally over time which does not really adhere to the functionality of this site. Especially, now the answer to the original question has been incorporated into the question, which renders the answer somewhat useless and its relation to the question unclear. Please do not do this! At least keep you original question, so that it is clear to future users what you asked originally and why people gave their answers like this. Better yet, ask a new question and refer via link to the old one.

Comment: I reverted your question back to its original version and added you latest edit to it in order to make clear what you had originally and what you still need from the answer that was given to your original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a start using a matrix for each box and a chain for the min/maj nodes.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, graphs, chains, ext.paths.ortho, ext.positioning-plus}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  chord list/.style args={#1/#2:#3}{
    matrix, rectangle, draw={#1}, fill={#1!10}, rounded corners, thick, name=#2,
    label={[anchor=north, node font=\Large\sffamily, text={#1}]north:{#2}},
    node contents={\tikzset{create chord list={#2}{#3}}\pgfmatrixendrow}},
  circ node/.style={
    thin, draw, fill=white, circle, inner sep=+.15em,
    text width=width("D$\flat$"), align=center},
  chord node/.style={inner xsep=+.15em, text depth=+0pt},
  create chord list/.code 2 args={
    \tikzset{node distance=+.2em and +.5em, start chain=chord#1 going west below, anchor=center}
    \path (up:2.3em);
    \foreach[remember=\first (initially 1), count=\i] \t/\N in {#2}{
      \foreach \n in \N \node[on chain, chord node] {\n};
      \node[circ node, left=of (chord#1-\first)(chord#1-\tikzchaincount)] (chord#1-label-\i) {\t};
      \unless\ifnum\first=\tikzchaincount\relax
        \path[black, thin] (chord#1-label-\i)
          edge (chord#1-\first.mid west) edge (chord#1-\tikzchaincount.mid west);
      \fi
      \edef\first{\pgfinteval{\tikzchaincount+1}}}}]
\matrix[                      chord list=green/iii:E/{min, min7, min9, maj6}];
\matrix[north right=  of iii, chord list=green/vi:{A/{min, min7, min9}, C/maj6}];
\matrix[north right=  of vi,  chord list=blue/ii:{F/{min, min7, min9}, F/maj6}];
\matrix[north right=  of ii,  chord list=blue/IV:{F/{maj, maj7, maj9, maj6/9, maj6}, D/min7}];
\matrix[north right=2:of IV,  chord list=green/I:C/{maj, maj7, maj9, maj6/9}];
\matrix[above=.5cm of (IV)(I),chord list=red/V:{G/{maj, dom7, dom9, 7$\sharp$5}, D$\flat$/dom7}];
\matrix[below=.5cm of (IV)(I),chord list=red/vii:{B/{dim, m7$\flat$5}, D/min6}];
\graph[
  edges={thick, >=Latex, only horizontal first},
  use existing nodes,
  oi/.style args={#1:#2}{out={#1}, in={#2}}]{
  iii -> vi -> ii -> IV <->[only horizontal second] I,
  iii ->[bend left, left anchor=north, right anchor=95] ii,
  V <->[oi=  0: 90] I,
  (V.200) <->[oi=180: 90] IV,
   V       ->[oi=180: 90] ii,
  (V.160) <->[oi=180: 90] vi,
  IV ->[oi=-90:180] vii
     ->[oi=  0:-90] I
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: @ABV It can be a start for you to complete your figure

Comment: How to add external arrows for the top lef matrix (I) as expected Chord progression map?